# Is it possible to programmatically load the same viewcontroller as the storyboard with the same instance address?

Tags: view, controller, storyboard, instance

I have the following question:
Is it possible to ask the StoryBoard to load a viewController without displayed it?

My problem is the following:
I have two viewController "Diaporamas" and "Settings". "Diaporamas" needs to know the state of a switch "With Frame:" from the viewController "Settings", but "Settings" is not loaded, because the customer has not selected them for the moment!

My tests:
I try this couple of calls:

```
    hc_Settings_Class = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsViewController"];
//  these line to force storyboard to load all controls in the "Settings" viewcontroller.
    hc_Parameters_Class.view.hidden = NO;
    [hc_AppDelegate_iPad loadPreferences];
```

the storyboard loads the right viewcontroller "Settings" but of course with an instance address different from the one instance loaded when the user selects them with the user interface. And of course, the "Diaporamas" viewcontroller doesn't know the real stat of all controls in the "Settings" viewcontroller!

Hope my question was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had an answer from another forum and effectively, I will using "NSUserDefaults" and use its feature that consist to function as a "singleton"! I was using a heavy mechanism which implemented global variables ...
Why make it complicated when it can be easier! 
I'll clean my code and have a better use of NSUserDefaults!

Thank you to everyone who took the time to read my question. ;-)